# Eclipse IDE Formatting/Colour settings for, easy readable code

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, eclipse-plugin, ide

I am currently learning JAVA and working on personal projects and for that i have to switch from `VScode` to `Eclipse`.

I have tried to tweak the formatting and colour setting but couldn't managed to set that will be easy to read.

I have tried to set the empty line after each methods, set max no. of char in a line and classname as `(Red)` as it help a bit when reading code.

I am just wondering if there is any obvious `template` that i can use to make my code more readable in Eclipse( i found few online some google template in XML format but with that i am getting erros), Also in VScode i had a lot of options to style and format the code including the plugins that i can download...

Any suggestion or advise please on how can I improve my code formatting and style ?

-`snippet`  from my current Eclipse IDE environment
[image: Screenshot of current look in Eclipse]

Comment: The installed theme may look fancy to you, but it is not as ergonomic as the built-in theme by far (and this particular theme may also slow down Eclipse and cause errors). When you work several hours a day, use a light theme. A dark theme is only better if everything is dark including other applications and the room you are. For the human eye it is stressful to switch between light and dark and more light is better than less light up to a maximum value.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the reply. Interesting to hear your prospective. Well I have been using Eclipse just for a month or two now was using before VScode for few months, the reason i switch to dark-black theme was only because as i understand colours with black most of the Screen will help as less light will be encountered by the eyes.